# Product URL Key gets deleted when importing custom options - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, importexport

I have been able to successfully import product custom options on my Magento 2 website.

But after the import when I check I can see the URL key that was there in the backend is deleted. Every time I import a product the URL Key is deleted.

I don't see any error log in the `var/log` directory.